# Adding a class to the last p element within a parent container

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I'm trying to add a class to the final

```
< p >
```

tag in my markup using the following jQuery code.

```
$('div.jobpost_body p:last').addClass('classificationsContainer');
```

I'm currently able to do this using CSS3 in modern browsers however I need to support as far back as IE7. For some reason this code is not applying the 'classificationsContainer' class to the last p tag in the div with a class of jobpost_body as is specified above.

Is there any way in which I can refactor this statement so ensure cross browser compatibility?

My html can be found below:

```
<div class="jobpost_body">
<h2>
<a href="#">Academic Administrator</a>
</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>
 <span class="jobclass even organisation">
 <span class="jobclass_type">Organisation</span>
 <span class="jobvalue">&nbsp;Test</span>&nbsp;</span>
 <span class="jobclass uneven school/department">
 <span class="jobclass_type">School/Department:</span>
 <span class="jobvalue">&nbsp;Test</span>&nbsp;</span>
 <span class="jobclass even based_at">
 <span class="jobclass_type">Based at:</span>
 <span class="jobvalue">&nbsp;Oxfordshire</span>&nbsp;</span>
 <span class="jobclass uneven hours_of_work">
 <span class="jobclass_type">Hours of work:</span>
 <span class="jobvalue"> &nbsp;37 hours per week</span>&nbsp;</span>
 </p>
</div>
```

I haven't created the html by the way so please no comments regarding how it is invalid etc.

Comment: You've said the class-name isn't added to the last `p`, but are there any errors reported? And does `p:last-child` respond any differently (it shouldn't, but I think your original attempt should work anyway)?

Comment: Which jquery version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately none of the solution provided above appear to work within my solution. I have therefore had to approach this via different means. As this < p > tag will always include at least one child with the class of .jobclass then I can simply apply a class to the parent of this selector to target the last < p > tag.

```
    $('span.jobclass').parent().addClass('classificationsContainer');
```

Thanks to everyone who provided solutions however this seems to be the best one in the end for my situation.

Comment: If all those solutions did not work (which they should have), then maybe something else in your code is the problem, not that.

Answer (score 2):

Give .last() a shot :

```
$('div.jobpost_body p').last().addClass('classificationsContainer');
```

Supports IE 7.
**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8grd3/1/)**

Comment: isn't it the same as using ':last' as anyway this is a sizzle selector, not CSS

Comment: @A.Wolff IE7 does not support the css selector.

Comment: Which CSS selector? ':last' is not a CSS selector

Comment: @A.Wolff It is an extended css3 selector.

Comment: @jezzipin ya a CSS selector extended by sizzle, just like i said... And so .last() or ':last' are exactly working the same

Answer (score 2):

And use `find()` to select sub content, its much faster selector:

```
$('div.jobpost_body').find("p").last().addClass('classificationsContainer');
```

Comment: isn't it the same as using ':last' as anyway this is a sizzle selector, not CSS

Comment: @PatsyIssa this is not the point here as OP was not using '> p' but ' p'. .find() method is faster than using as selector ' p'

Comment: @reyaner have you tested it on IE7?